# Hibernate Validator check array size

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I would like to check an String with hibernate validator that it has inside 2 other Strings (created from combine first_name and last_name).
I mean something like this

```
stringExample.getName().split(" ").length == 2 //returns boolean value
```

where 
stringExample = "first_name last_name";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `javax.validation.constraints.Pattern` annotation to validate the concatenated full name

```
public class Test {

    static class User {
        @Pattern(regexp = "\\S+\\s+\\S+") // names delimited by one or more spaces
        String fullName;

        public User(String fullName) {
            this.fullName = fullName;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        validator.validate(new User("Fname")).size(); // 1 validation error
        validator.validate(new User("Fname Lname")).size(); // 0 validation errors
    }
}
```